# Json decode not working when parsing in laravel view

Tags: php, json, laravel

No error or output shows up when decoding in laravel view.

The function in my controller

```
public function getOrderHistory(){
        $orders = Processing::where('client_id', auth()->user()->id)->get('order_details');
        return view('pages.purchase', compact('orders', json_decode($orders)));
    }
```

My Laravel View

```
 @foreach ($orders as $order)
 <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">{{ $order->name }}</h5>
 <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">Accepted</p>
 <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-1">
 <h6 class="font-weight-bold my-2">Price: $100</h6>
  </div>
 @endforeach
```

Mysql order_details column

```
{"order_id":2,"quantity":1,"name":"Atque beatae quia omnis."}
```

Comment: `json_decode($orders)` may easily fail without you ever checking in your code. That probably would have become obvious if you had created a [mcve], as required here. Please, as a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `$orders` is actual array containing JSON values:

```php
$orders = [
    '{"order_id":2,"quantity":1,"name":"Atque beatae quia omnis."}',
    /* ... */
];
```

so your `json_decode` does not work on array (use [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to get errors.

In order to decode all your orders, you can do

```php
$orders = array_map('json_decode', $orders); // pass each element of $orders into `json_decode`
```

---

Since you are storing all info into single column I assume that your database structure is bad and will cause issues in future. E.g. finding all orders with `quantity > 3`. Maybe better have separate columns for that or whole table mapped by Foreign Keys?

Answer (score 0):

your $order is collection of Processing model! json_decode function not work in collection.

your $orders variable in foreach blade is first passed value from controller (collection of order model) not decoded value

delete json_decode($orders) :

```
public function getOrderHistory(){
        $orders = Processing::where('client_id', auth()->user()->id)->get('order_details');
        return view('pages.purchase', compact('orders'));
    }
```

change view to bellow:

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    @php
        $order_data=json_decode($order->order_details , true);
    @endphp
    <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">{{ $order_data['name'] }}</h5>
    <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">Accepted</p>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-1">
        <h6 class="font-weight-bold my-2">Price: $100</h6>
    </div>
@endforeach
```